# Is this a bug in DiscretizeRegion in 10.4?

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.1**

---

Consider the following implicit region:

```
imp = ImplicitRegion[((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 == 
    0, {{x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}}];
```

In *Mathematica* **10.3.1**, we can easily discretize it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version **10.4**, this fails:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It doesn't matter what `MaxCellMeasure` you use, it still fails. I know it's a back slide, but is this due to some bug and can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: I can confirm that it fails on my 10.4 Win7-64 as well.

Comment: This is a bug, for a workaround try `Method -> "Semialgebraic"`.

Comment: Fails on Kubuntu 1510 64 bit. ilians workaround works well! +1

Comment: @Xavier this still fails for me `"11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"`

Comment: @mikado Thanks for checking, I've updated the bug banner.

Comment: This worked for me on 11.0.0 for Linux 64-bit on a fresh start of Mathematica. However, I have been using `ImplicitRegion` with `DiscretizeRegion` a lot since  v 10.0 came out and I have noticed very inconsistent behavior. I have seen the same code work, then not work. It bothers me that `ContourPlot` is fast and correct but `DiscretizeRegion` is slow and inconsistent. I have made my own "DiscretizeRegion" based on extracting data from `ContourPlot` which works well for my special cases.

Comment: @c186282 OK, I'm rolling back to the initial banner.

Comment: @mikado Please see the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is fixed in **11.1**

```
imp = ImplicitRegion[((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 == 
    0, {{x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}}];

DiscretizeRegion[imp, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]